# placing on div in the bottom of another div, relatively

Tags: css

I have 2 divs and I want one of them to appeare at the bottom of the other, relatively.

```
<div class="div1">
 <div class="div2">
 </div>
</div>
```

The CSS code:

```
.div1
{
 position: relative; 
}
.div2
{
 position: relative; 
 bottom: 0;
}
```

for some reason div2 is appearing at the top of div1.
(changing absolute doesn't help because I want div2 to resize with div1 when the whole page is resized).
How can I do it?

Comment: You are using classes, and then using the `#` in your css which means ID. Try using `.div1 { ...`

Comment: sorry,the mistake is just here, the original code is right. I editted it now

Answer (score 1):

You need to change position:relative on your inner div to be position:absolute and add in some width/height on the divs: http://jsfiddle.net/H7kq6/1/

```
.div1
{
 position: relative;
    background:pink;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
}
.div2
{
    background:#ccc;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
    height:10px;
    width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct but there is one error according your CSS, the HTML should be like:

```
<div id="div1">
    first div
    <br /> 
    <br />
 <div id="div2">
     second div
 </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/saidbakr/3uRuM/

Comment: yes, the mistake is only here. I fixed it, but div2 is still at the top of div1